# How to access components from another module with PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I made a minimum working environment for this question.

First I have this UI file ([GDrive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OSnGmCn9AFLRpkhwrwd338Tlr6vWccCm/view?usp=sharing)),which I'll later load in my UI.py.[image], which I'll later load in my

The UI.py goes thus:

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt6 import uic


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(r"C:\Documents\Qt Designer\mwe.ui") # Change it to yoour own .ui

        self.txtBox = self.findChild(QPlainTextEdit, 'plainTextEdit')
        self.ui.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    import main

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Essentially, what I want to do is to access this PlainTextEditor in main.py, becuase that's where I'll write the functions.

```
import UI

UI.Window.txtBox.insertPlainText('foo')
```

But when I try to run UI.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\dynamic_ui_foo\UI.py", line 18, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\dynamic_ui_foo\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    UI.Window.txtBox.insertPlainText('foo')
AttributeError: type object 'Window' has no attribute 'txtBox'
```

It says Window doesn't have this attribute. How do I access the components from another module? And am I going in the right way by separating UI codes and function codes (I know the cross-importing looks terrible).

Comment: The GUI is *already* separated by defining it in a Qt Designer file. And your *UI.py* file is *already* the separate module where the program logic should go. You have now discovered one reason why doing things this way is a good idea: it makes it *much* easier to access the widgets you defined in the designer file. But you could make it even easier by avoiding the very bad practice of using `findChild` to access widgets. Instead, create the ui this way:  `self.ui = uic.loadUi(path, self)`. Then you can simply do: `self.ui.plainTextEdit.insertPlainText('foo')`.

Comment: In GUI programs, most of the functionality should be coded as responses to events and signals. So you might connect a button's `clicked` signal to a method added to your `Window` class. This method might then access another widget (such as a text-box), and modify it in some way (e.g. by inserting some text). Thus, the main logic of the program is driven by user interaction and/or external events coming from the system. I hope this makes it clear that putting all your code in another module and executing *procedurally* just isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate your error message, consider the following example:

```
class bla:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'test'


print(bla.foo) # <-- results in your error

b = bla()
print(b.foo) # <-- this is what you would like to access
```

Right now you are trying to access txtBox of the class `Window`, but you need to access txtBox from your instance `window`.

However, I have doubts about it working in the way you do your imports.
I would suggest to move

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI.Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

to main.py. Use UI.py to only define the layout. Changing the text `txtBox` can be implemented either as a method of `Window`:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    # init code
    def change_content(self, content):
        self.txtBox.insertPlainText(content)
```

Then in main you call that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI.Window()
    window.change_content()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Of course you can use a more direct approach:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI.Window()
    window.txtBox.insertPlainText(content)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The last example seems to be easier. But that way, if you change txtBox to something else you need to keep in mind to also do changes in `main.py`. With the first example you only have to do changes in `UI.py`.

Edit:
Added missing argument `self`. Thanks to musicamante for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that `change_content` will throw an exception, since the first argument of instance methods is always the instance itself ("self"), and `insertPlainText` expects a string instead. It should be `def change_content(self, content):`